# Location directive not working when using php-fpm (via mod_fastcgi)

Tags: apache-2.2, php-fpm, mod-fastcgi

I've configured a virtualhost which should be completely restricted with a SSL client certificate, except one location (/Public).

My configuration in my virtualhost:

```
<Location ~ ^/(?!Public)>
        SSLRequireSSL
        SSLVerifyClient require
        SSLVerifyDepth 10
        SSLOptions +StdEnvVars -ExportCertData
</Location>
```

I've done a couple of tests using mod_fastcgi:
Requesting `https://myserver.mycompany.com/MyWorkspace`, the server is requesting SSL client certicate -> Works as designed.
Requesting `https://myserver.mycompany.com/Public/index.html`, the server is not requesting SSL client certicate -> Works as designed.
Requesting `https://myserver.mycompany.com/Public/index.php`, the server is requesting SSL client certicate -> Works NOT as designed.

When I do the last test using mod_php, the server is not requesting for a SSL client certificate, which is correct.

Is this normal behavior, or did I misconfigured something?

My config for mod_fastcgi is as follows:

```
LoadModule fastcgi_module modules/mod_fastcgi.so

<IfModule mod_fastcgi.c>
    DirectoryIndex index.php index.html index.shtml index.cgi
    AddHandler php5-fcgi .php
    Action php5-fcgi /php5-fcgi
    Alias /php5-fcgi /usr/lib/cgi-bin/php5-fcgi
    FastCgiExternalServer /usr/lib/cgi-bin/php5-fcgi -socket
/dev/shm/php5-fpm.sock -pass-header Authorization

    # For monitoring status with e.g. Munin
    <LocationMatch "/(ping|status)">
        SetHandler php5-fcgi-virt
        Action php5-fcgi-virt /php5-fcgi virtual
    </LocationMatch>
</IfModule>
```

Apache version: httpd-2.2.15-39.el6.centos.x86_64
PHP version: php56w-fpm-5.6.4-1.w6.x86_64